# Best nested parallelization approach with Rust Futures

Tags: rust, threadpool, rust-futures

Not sure if this is even a good question to ask but I hope that the answer could also cover if nested parallelization is bad or not in addition to my main questions. Thank you so much!

Suppose I have tasks a, b, c and d. These tasks each have their separate sub tasks, a1, a2 so on..

Sometimes, a1 might have a bunch of sub tasks to accomplish as well. The tasks are nested inside a, b, c and d because they are dependent on processing together as a whole, so there won't be a way to decouple them and create tasks e, f and g (so on..).

I am currently **utilising Futures and Threadpool** to process these tasks in a concurrent, parallel way (such that a, b.. run in parallel, and a1, a2 run in parallel).

However, I was greeted with

```
thread 'tokio-runtime-worker' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Os { code: 35, kind: WouldBlock, message: "Resource temporarily unavailable" }', src/my_folder/my_file.rs:123:123
```

The code above that failed is

```
let thread_pool = ThreadPool::new().unwrap();
```

So the questions are:

1. Is nested parallelization correct in this case? (If not, what should I do? If yes, how should I do?)
2. How do I ensure that Threadpools are created safely, such that it would not fail unwrapping when the resources are inadequate?
3. If (2) is a wrong thing to do, how should I implement my code?

```rust
let tasks: Vec<_> = block_transactions.into_iter()
    .map(|encoded_tx| {
        let pool = core_pool.clone();
        let rpc_url = core_rpc_url.clone();
        let block = core_block.clone();

        tokio::spawn(async move {
            let sol_client = RpcClient::new(rpc_url.clone());

            let mut tx = crate::models::transactions::Transaction {
                hash: "".to_string(),
                block: block.number.clone(),
                is_confirmed: true,
                status: TransactionStatus::Success,
                fee: 0,
                timestamp: block.timestamp.clone()
            };

            if let Some(decoded_tx) = (&encoded_tx.transaction).decode() {
                // Each item in the signatures array is a digital signature
                // of the given message

                // Additional safety net
                if decoded_tx.signatures.len() >= 1 {
                    // Signatures should be Vec<Signature>.
                    // The first one, signatures[0], is the hash that is used to
                    // identify the transaction (eg. in the explorer), and you can
                    // get the base58-encoded string using the .to_string() method.
                    // Seed first signature
                    tx.hash = decoded_tx.signatures[0].to_string();

                    // Seed the transaction
                    let tx_res = crate::actions::transactions::create_or_ignore_transaction(
                        &*pool.get().unwrap(),
                        &tx,
                    );

                    // Seed everything that depends ONLY on the created transaction
                    if let Ok(created_tx) = tx_res {
                        // Spawn the futures threader first
                        let thread_pool = ThreadPool::new().unwrap();

                        // Seed subsequents
                        let tst_pool = pool.clone();
                        let tst_dtx = decoded_tx.clone();
                        let tst_tx = tx.clone();
                        let transaction_signatures_task = async move {
                            let transaction_signatures: Vec<_> = tst_dtx
                                .signatures
                                .as_slice()
                                .into_par_iter()
                                .filter(|signature| &signature.to_string() != &tst_tx.hash)
                                .map(|signature| {
                                    // Subsequent signature are lead to the same tx, just
                                    // signed from a different key pair.
                                    InsertableTransactionSignature {
                                        transaction_hash: tst_tx.hash.clone(),
                                        signature: signature.to_string().clone(),
                                        timestamp: tst_tx.timestamp.clone(),
                                    }
                                })
                                .collect();

                            let cts_result =
                                crate::actions::transaction_signatures::create_transaction_signatures(
                                    &*tst_pool.get().unwrap(),
                                    transaction_signatures.as_slice(),
                                );

                            if let Ok(created_ts) = cts_result {
                                if created_ts.len() != (tst_dtx.signatures.len() - 1) {
                                    eprintln!("[processors/transaction] WARN: Looks like there's a signature \
                        creation count mismatch for tx {}", tst_tx.hash.clone());
                                }
                            } else {
                                let cts_result_err = cts_result.err().unwrap();
                                eprintln!(
                                    "[processors/transaction] FATAL: signature seeding error for \
                    tx {} due to: {}",
                                    tst_tx.hash.clone(),
                                    cts_result_err.to_string()
                                );
                            }
                        };
                        let tst_handle = thread_pool
                            .spawn_with_handle(transaction_signatures_task)
                            .unwrap();

                        // A message contains a header,
                        // The message header contains three unsigned 8-bit values.
                        // The first value is the number of required signatures in the
                        // containing transaction. The second value is the number of those
                        // corresponding account addresses that are read-only.
                        // The third value in the message header is the number of read-only
                        // account addresses not requiring signatures.
                        // identify which are required addresses, addresses requesting write
                        // access, then address with readonly access
                        let req_sig_count =
                            (decoded_tx.message.header.num_required_signatures.clone()) as usize;
                        let rw_sig_count = (decoded_tx
                            .message
                            .header
                            .num_readonly_signed_accounts
                            .clone()) as usize;
                        let ro_sig_count = (decoded_tx
                            .message
                            .header
                            .num_readonly_unsigned_accounts
                            .clone()) as usize;

                        // tx.message.account_keys is a compact-array of account addresses,
                        // The addresses that require signatures appear at the beginning of the
                        // account address array, with addresses requesting write access first
                        // and read-only accounts following. The addresses that do not require
                        // signatures follow the addresses that do, again with read-write
                        // accounts first and read-only accounts following.
                        let at_pool = pool.clone();
                        let at_tx = tx.clone();
                        let at_dtx = decoded_tx.clone();
                        let at_block = block.clone();
                        let accounts_task = async move {
                            crate::processors::account::process_account_data(
                            &at_pool,
                            &sol_client,
                            &at_tx.hash,
                            &req_sig_count,
                            &rw_sig_count,
                            &ro_sig_count,
                            &at_dtx.message.account_keys,
                            &at_block.timestamp)
                                .await;
                        };
                        let at_handle = thread_pool
                            .spawn_with_handle(accounts_task)
                            .unwrap();

                        // Each instruction specifies a single program, a subset of
                        // the transaction's accounts that should be passed to the program,
                        // and a data byte array that is passed to the program. The program
                        // interprets the data array and operates on the accounts specified
                        // by the instructions. The program can return successfully, or
                        // with an error code. An error return causes the entire
                        // transaction to fail immediately.
                        let it_pool = pool.clone();
                        let it_ctx = created_tx.clone();
                        let it_dtx = decoded_tx.clone();
                        let instruction_task = async move {
                            crate::processors::instruction::
                            process_instructions(&it_pool, &it_dtx,
                                                 &it_ctx,
                                                 it_dtx.message.instructions.as_slice(),
                                                 it_dtx.message.account_keys.as_slice())
                                .await;
                        };
                        let it_handle = thread_pool
                            .spawn_with_handle(instruction_task)
                            .unwrap();

                        // Ensure we have the tx meta as well
                        let tmt_pool = pool.clone();
                        let tmt_block = block.clone();
                        let tmt_meta = encoded_tx.meta.clone();
                        let tx_meta_task = async move {
                            if let Some(tx_meta) = tmt_meta {
                                let tm_thread_pool = ThreadPool::new().unwrap();

                                // Process the transaction's meta and validate the various
                                // data structures. Seed the accounts, alternate tx hashes,
                                // logs, balance inputs first
                                // pub log_messages: Option<Vec<String>>,
                                let tlt_pool = tmt_pool.clone();
                                let tlt_txm = tx_meta.clone();
                                let tlt_tx = tx.clone();
                                let transaction_log_task = async move {
                                    if let Some(log_messages) = &tlt_txm.log_messages {
                                        let transaction_logs =
                                            log_messages.into_par_iter().enumerate()
                                                .map(|(idx, log_msg)| {
                                                    InsertableTransactionLog {
                                                        transaction_hash: tlt_tx.hash.clone(),
                                                        data: log_msg.clone(),
                                                        line: idx as i32,
                                                        timestamp: tlt_tx.timestamp.clone()
                                                    }
                                                })
                                                .collect::<Vec<InsertableTransactionLog>>();

                                        let tl_result = crate::actions::transaction_logs::batch_create(
                                            &*tlt_pool.get().unwrap(),
                                            transaction_logs.as_slice()
                                        );

                                        if let Err(err) = tl_result {
                                            eprintln!("[processors/transaction] WARN: Problem pushing \
                                    transaction logs for tx {} due to {}", tlt_tx.hash.clone(),
                                                      err.to_string());
                                        }
                                    }
                                };
                                let tlt_handle = tm_thread_pool
                                    .spawn_with_handle(transaction_log_task)
                                    .unwrap();

                                // Gather and seed all account inputs
                                let ait_pool = tmt_pool.clone();
                                let ait_txm = tx_meta.clone();
                                let ait_tx = tx.clone();
                                let ait_dtx = decoded_tx.clone();
                                let account_inputs_task = async move {
                                    let account_inputs: Vec<InsertableAccountInput> = (0..ait_dtx.message.account_keys.len())
                                        .into_par_iter()
                                        .map(|i| {
                                            let current_account_hash =
                                                ait_dtx.message.account_keys[i].clone().to_string();

                                            InsertableAccountInput {
                                                transaction_hash: ait_tx.hash.clone(),
                                                account: current_account_hash.to_string(),
                                                token_id: "".to_string(),
                                                pre_balance: (ait_txm.pre_balances[i] as i64),
                                                post_balance: Option::from(ait_txm.post_balances[i] as i64),
                                                timestamp: block.timestamp.clone()
                                            }
                                        }).collect();

                                    let result = crate::actions::account_inputs::batch_create(
                                        &*ait_pool.get().unwrap(),
                                        account_inputs);

                                    if let Err(error) = result {
                                        eprintln!("[processors/transaction] FATAL: Problem indexing \
                                    account inputs for tx {} due to {}", ait_tx.hash.clone(),
                                                  error.to_string());
                                    }
                                };
                                let ait_handle = tm_thread_pool
                                    .spawn_with_handle(account_inputs_task)
                                    .unwrap();

                                // If there are token balances for this transaction
                                // pub pre_token_balances: Option<Vec<UiTransactionTokenBalance>>,
                                // pub post_token_balances: Option<Vec<UiTransactionTokenBalance>>,
                                let tai_pool = tmt_pool.clone();
                                let tai_txm = tx_meta.clone();
                                let tai_tx = tx.clone();
                                let tai_block = tmt_block.clone();
                                let tai_dtx = decoded_tx.clone();
                                let token_account_inputs_task = async move {
                                    if let (Some(pre_token_balances),
                                        Some(post_token_balances)) =
                                    (tai_txm.pre_token_balances, tai_txm.post_token_balances)
                                    {
                                        super::account_input::process_token_account_inputs(
                                            &tai_pool,
                                            &tai_tx.hash,
                                            &pre_token_balances,
                                            &post_token_balances,
                                            &tai_dtx.message.account_keys,
                                            &tai_block.timestamp,
                                        ).await;
                                    }
                                };
                                let tai_handle = tm_thread_pool
                                    .spawn_with_handle(token_account_inputs_task)
                                    .unwrap();

                                let iit_pool = tmt_pool.clone();
                                let iit_dtx = decoded_tx.clone();
                                let iit_txm = tx_meta.clone();
                                let iit_tx = tx.clone();
                                let inner_instructions_task = async move {
                                    if let Some(inner_instructions) = iit_txm.inner_instructions {
                                        crate::processors::inner_instruction::process(&iit_pool,
                                                                                      inner_instructions.as_slice(),
                                                                                      &iit_dtx, &iit_tx,
                                                                                      iit_dtx.message.account_keys.as_slice())
                                            .await;
                                    }
                                };
                                let iit_handle = tm_thread_pool
                                    .spawn_with_handle(inner_instructions_task)
                                    .unwrap();

                                let tasks_future = future::join_all(vec![tlt_handle, ait_handle, tai_handle, iit_handle]);
                                tasks_future.await;

                                // Update the tx's metadata and proceed with instructions processing
                                let update_result =
                                    crate::actions::transactions::update(&*tmt_pool.get().unwrap(), &tx);

                                if let Err(update_err) = update_result {
                                        eprintln!(
                                            "[blockchain_syncer] FATAL: Problem updating tx: {}",
                                            update_err
                                        );
                                    }
                            } else {
                                eprintln!(
                                    "[processors/transaction] WARN: tx {} has no metadata!",
                                    tx.hash
                                );
                            }
                        };
                        let tmt_handle = thread_pool
                            .spawn_with_handle(tx_meta_task)
                            .unwrap();

                        let future_batch =
                            future::join_all(vec![at_handle, it_handle, tst_handle, tmt_handle]);

                        future_batch.await;
                    } else {
                        let tx_err = tx_res.err();

                        if let Some(err) = tx_err {
                            eprintln!(
                                "[blockchain_syncer] WARN: Problem pushing tx {} to DB \
                            due to: {}",
                                tx.hash, err
                            )
                        } else {
                            eprintln!(
                                "[blockchain_syncer] FATAL: Problem pushing tx {} to DB \
                            due to an unknown error",
                                tx.hash
                            );
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    eprintln!(
                        "[blockchain_syncer] FATAL: a transaction in block {} has no hashes!",
                        &block.number
                    );
                }
            } else {
                eprintln!(
                    "[blockchain_syncer] FATAL: Unable to obtain \
                                    account information vec from chain for tx {}",
                    &tx.hash
                );
            }
        })
    })
    .collect();

future::join_all(tasks).await;
```

Comment: I'm not a Rust expert, but the answer to question #2 seems to be that instead of `unwrap`ping the threadpool, you could just `if let` or `match` it, so the code won't panic on a possible error; then maybe retry creating the threadpool later.

Comment: Multiplying the thread pools like that is a bad idea. Instead you should `tokio::spawn` everything and let Tokio handle the threads.

Comment: @Jmb Would nested tokio::spawn tasks allow me to run each iteration's tasks in parallel? Because it seems like the program is not utilising the entire CPU capacity of the machine when the highest layer of the nesting has the threadpool.

Comment: @FZs Yup! But what i'm looking for is specifically on the waiting part. Like what's the best practice/sample to move into that approach.

Comment: Yes, assuming your workload _can_ use the entire CPU capacity. In particular it looks like you're doing RPC, so if all your threads are waiting for an RPC response, then they can't saturate your CPU no matter how many threads you run them in.

Comment: Yup I am! @Jmb Fortunately, I made sure that a new RPC client is instantiated every time we head down into a new scope (Since the RPC servers are designed to handle this behaviour). So the main problem boils down to the usage of reactors in Tokio.. I can't seem to wrap my head around the reactors error..

```thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'there is no reactor running, must be called from the context of a Tokio 1.x runtime', src/processors/transaction.rs:129:47
stack backtrace:```